# How do I pass data from a chrome extension to a web page it opened using window.open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension which opens a web page (new tab) on certain criteria. once the web page loads I need to pass data to the newly opened window. How do I do it?

Comment: no, didnt seem possible

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass data from Chrome Extension to a web page using window.open. Sending messages to web pages are similar to  [cross-extension messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging). Your app or extension can receive and respond to messages from regular web pages. From web page, use the *'runtime.sendMessage'* or *'runtime.connect'* APIs to send a message to a specific app or extension.

You may listen to messages from web pages via *'runtime.onMessageExternal'* or *'runtime.onConnectExternal'* APIs,. Here is an example:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
if (sender.url == blacklistedWebsite)
return; // don't allow this web page access
if (request.openUrlInEditor)
openUrl(request.openUrlInEditor);
});
```